# Why in jQuery core.js isn't extend defined with a prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

Why in jQuery `core.js` isn't `extend` defined as like this:

```
jQuery.extend = jQuery.fn.extend = function() {
    ...
}
```

and not as a prototype like:

```
jQuery.prototype.extend = jQuery.fn.prototype.extend = function() {
    ...
}
```

Presumably with the former, objects created from jQuery will not have the extend function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `jQuery.fn === jQuery.prototype`

It is defined on the prototype. jQuery just decided it would be "cute" to alias the prototype to `.fn`

Which is why

```
$().extend({ 
    "lulz": "baz" 
}, { 
    "more-lulz": "no wai" 
})["more-lulz"] === "no wai"; // true
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, because `fn` is nothing than a shortcut to the `prototype` property :

```
console.log($.prototype === $.fn);
```

Maybe John Resig got bored of typing `prototype` for every method and set up a nice alias `fn` (which is indeed shorter and in my opinion more suggestive).

Comment: O yer missed that one, it sort of masks prototype a little which makes it slightly more difficult to read for the sake of 7 letters but who am I to argue with John Resig